# Check if Vim split window is most bottom/most right

Tags: vim

Is it possible in VimScript to detect if a split window touches the bottom and/or right margin of the real window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

BITS BROKEN:

```
func! IsMostBottomRight(nr)
  let oldw = winnr()
  silent! exe "normal! \<c-w>l"
  silent! exe "normal! \<c-w>j"
  let neww = winnr()
  silent! exe oldw.'wincmd w'
  return oldw == neww
endfunction

" echo IsMostBottomRight(winnr())
```

FIXED:

```
func! IsMostBottomRight()
  let oldw = winnr()
  silent! exe "normal! \<c-w>l"
  silent! exe "normal! \<c-w>j"
  let neww = winnr()
  silent! exe oldw.'wincmd w'
  return oldw == neww
endfunction

" echo IsMostBottomRight()
```

Comment: This might seem like a bit of a hack but it's the only way I know of accomplishing the desired result.

Comment: I had to split it into two functions (I need bottom and right separately), and remove the argument (which isn't necessary here). Other than that, works as advertised.